# Почему не работает код всплывающих подсказок?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь реализовать как можно практичный код вывода подсказок-сообщений.

```
var text1="Заполните это поле и будет Вам счастье!";
function showMessage(where, what){
    var parentElem=where.nextSibling;
    var newDiv=document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.innerHTML=text1;
    parentElem.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Здесь таблица онли

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input onclick="showMessage(this.parentNode, text1)" class="inp" type="text"/>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Подумайте над вопросами:

1. что такое text1 в "showMessage(this.parentNode, text1)"
2. зачем передается параметр what в showMessage() если потом не используется ?

Comment: @iKuzko, это вам стоило бы подумать над тем, что написали! Вы слыхали о такой штуке, как "необязательные параметры функции". Видимо нет, раз пишете пункт два =) А что насчет первого пункта, так это то, что вас просто подвела внимательность! Вот инициализация:

    var text1="Заполните это поле и будет Вам счастье!";

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что вам нужен не просто следующий узел, а следующий узел, который является DOM-элементом.

То есть, нужна вот [такая функция](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_node_nextsibling.asp):

```
function get_nextsibling(n) {
  x=n.nextSibling;
  while (x.nodeType!=Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    x=x.nextSibling;
  }
  return x;
}
```

и родительский элемент для подсказки получать вот так:

```
var parentElem=get_nextsibling(where);
```

В вашем варианте получается так, что в качестве nextSibling приходит текст, который идет после тега input (кажется, что там ничего нет, но на самом деле есть пробелы и '\n'). В принципе, если весь html-код записать в одну строчку без пробелов, ваш вариант будет работать.